# Create df after looping through another df and generating stats

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I would like to generate a new df

```
for c in df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]):
  sk = skew(df[c])
  kt = kurtosis(df[c])
```

How can i transform this snippet to a dataframe that looks like this:

| col_name | skewness | kurtosis |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col_a | 0.1 | 2 |
| col_b | 3 | 0.5 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use [`pandas.DataFrame.kurtosis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.kurtosis.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.skew`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.skew.html)?

Example:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'b': [1, 2, 2, 3, 0], 'c': [-1, 5, 4.6, 10.3, 11]})
>>> pd.concat([df.skew(), df.kurtosis()], axis=1).reset_index().rename({'index': 'col_name', 0: 'skewness', 1: 'kurtosis'}, axis=1)
  col_name  skewness  kurtosis
0        b -0.404796 -0.177515
1        c -0.487970 -0.620300
```

Comment: awesome answer. i added the name parameter in the to_frame